# How do I make this script more efficient?

Tags: python

I have a python script that does something like the following:

```
def callAPI():
    #call the API here and get a response
    return APIResponseValue

do while callAPI() > 5:
    if callAPI() = 2:
        #do something        
do while callAPI() < 5:
    #do something else here
```

Inside the do while statement, I want to get the value from callAPI.  How do I get that value without re-running the API call like I'm doing in the above?  The only way I know how do get that value would be to include something like "value = callAPI()" inside the do while statement.  Thanks for the help.  I'm obviously still learning.

Comment: There is no such thing as `do while` in Python.

Comment: typically a case for `while True:`. But your syntax is off. get the value in the infinite loop and break if > 5. Like that you don't have to compute it more than once.

Comment: good point.  I quickly wrote this in the text editor and didnt check it.  It's correct in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
apiResult = callAPI()

while apiResult > 5:
    if apiResult == 2:
        #do something        
    apiResult = callAPI()

while apiResult < 5:
    #do something else here
    apiResult = callAPI()
```

Please note that you assign the variable before starting the first loop, and call the "callAPI()" function again at the end of each loop.